# unable to set background color on iTextSharp signature appearance

Tags: itext

Does anyone have any ideas on how to set the background color on the PdfSignatureAppearance rectangle in iTextSharp?  I create the PdfSignatureAppearance object and can set its positioning on the page, but the rectangle only has a transparent background.  I'm trying to apply a color (any really).

I've tried creating a new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle then setting the `rect.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);`  That doesn't work.  I saw someone else trying to something similar by applying the styles to the layer2 of the signature appearance object.  I've tried these with no luck.

```
PdfTemplate sigAppLayer2 = appearance.GetLayer(2);
sigAppLayer2.SetRGBColorFill(255, 0, 0);
sigAppLayer2.SetGrayFill(2);
sigAppLayer2.BoundingBox.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

Anytime I try one of the above styling changes to the layer2 the visible signature disappears on the PDF.  If I try applying it to layer 0 or layer 1 then nothing happens.  I'm assuming then I'm touching the correct layer (2).

Any ideas?  The goal is to just get a background on the signature box vs having it be transparent.

See comment below. I tried this as well setting against layer 2 and layer 0.  Both result in a red box, but the signature text is missing.

```
PdfTemplate sigAppLayer2 = appearance.GetLayer(2);
Rectangle rect = sigAppLayer2.BoundingBox;
PdfTemplate sigAppLayer0 = appearance.GetLayer(0);
sigAppLayer0.SetRGBColorFill(255, 0, 0);
sigAppLayer0.Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Bottom, rect.Width, rect.Height);
sigAppLayer0.Fill();
```

Comment: *but the signature text is missing* - you are aware that after doing `appearance.GetLayer(2)` you have to add the writing yourself, aren't you? Either you leave drawing a layer to iText or you do it all by yourself.

Comment: I wasn't aware you can't manipulate layer2 without destroying it.  See the comment below.  Any ideas if there is a way to keep the text while setting the signature rectangle background?  I've tried to manipulate the rectangle parameter before it gets set to SetVisibleSignature method, but it doesn't seem to keep formatting through the signature block creation.

Comment: *I wasn't aware you can't manipulate layer2 without destroying it.* - More to the point, iText (during preClose) checks whether there already is some layer 2 material. If there is, it takes it (e.g. your rectangle) as is. If there is not, it creates its default layer 2 appearance.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm missing something then. I'm using the `PdfSignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature()` method first.  That creates layer 2, draws the rectangle and then sets the rectangle text to the signature data.  After that then I do the Get on layer 2 and use the bounding box to do the fill.  Maybe I'm reading your comment wrong, but if the layer 2 already exists then shouldn't it keep it as is instead of making the text disappear?

Comment: *I'm using the PdfSignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature() method first. That creates layer 2,* - no, it doesn't. The first `GetLayer(2)` call creates an empty layer2, and only if there is no layer2 yet during `PreClose`,  iText creates a layer2 and adds some text to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the rectangle and fill that rectangle with the fill color.

From memory (untested), you need something like this:

```
PdfTemplate sigAppLayer2 = appearance.GetLayer(2);
Rectangle rect = sigAppLayer2.BoundingBox;
sigAppLayer2.SetRGBColorFill(255, 0, 0);
sigAppLayer2.Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Bottom, rect.Width, rect.Height);
sigAppLayer2.Fill();
```

Comment: Thanks.  That put me closer to a solution. If I do this method I get a red box where the signature box is, but now all the signature text is missing.  I also tried getting the bounding box rectangle dimensions from layer 2 and then building a layer 0 filled rectangle with the same dimensions.  This also creates the red rectangle, but the signature text is also missing here. Any ideas?

Comment: If you add the text first and then add the rectangle, then the rectangle will cover the text. The text will be there, but you won't see it for reasons that should be obvious.

Comment: thanks.  that makes sense. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this best practice?  I'm using the `appearance.SetVisibleSignature()` method to create the signature rectangle.  It is what creates the text.  The issue is that it seems that he layer2 and its boundingbox doesn't exist yet if I try to create the color filled rectangle first

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```
    PdfTemplate sigAppLayer2 = appearance.GetLayer(2);
    Rectangle rect = sigAppLayer2.BoundingBox;
    sigAppLayer2.SetRGBColorFill(255, 0, 0);
    sigAppLayer2.Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Bottom, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    sigAppLayer2.Fill();

    sigAppLayer2.ResetRGBColorFill();// <--------- you needs this

    sigAppLayer2.BeginText() ...etc
```